# what is the difference between target value blank,self, parent,top in HTML?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

what is the difference between  target value blank,self, parent,top,framename in  tag target attribute?
i know blank is open than link in new tab 
self is  that link open   in current tab 
But i can't understand parent and top

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the specification:

> _blank
>
> The user agent should load the designated document in a new, unnamed
>   window.
>
> _self
>
> The user agent should load the document in the same frame as the
>   element that refers to this target.
>
> _parent
>
> The user agent should load the document into the immediate FRAMESET
>   parent of the current frame. This value is equivalent to _self if the
>   current frame has no parent.
>
> _top
>
> The user agent should load the document into the full, original window
>   (thus canceling all other frames). This value is equivalent to _self
>   if the current frame has no parent.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-frame-target

Comment: Please note that many browsers also accept `target="_tab"` to open in a new tab. However, this is not standard according to the W3C or WHATWG.

Comment: @MrLister — Are you sure that is explicit support and not just the combination of a link to a new *named* window meeting the "Open new windows in new tabs" preference?

Answer (score 3):

```
target="_blank"
```

Opens a new window and show the related data.

```
target="_self"
```

Opens the window in the same frame, it means existing window itself.

```
target="_top"
```

Opens the linked document in the full body of the window.

```
target="_parent"
```

Opens data in the size of parent window.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-frame-target